# Issues with concealing latex

Tags: neovim, conceal

I am playing around with conceal options in latex, and I would appreciate some help. I am using neovim os OS X if that makes a difference. I have the following settings in my config file

```
Plug 'lervag/vimtex'


let g:tex_flavor='latex'
hi Conceal ctermfg=Blue
```

(full config [here](https://pastebin.pl/view/a5f7fdef) in case it's necessary)

But this is completely ignored, and when I open vim in a math file the following happens,
[image: what is happening]

I tried adding "hi clear Conceal" to the config file, but this gets ignored as well. I should add that both commands work when I call them from vim (i.e. :hi clear Conceal, :hi Conceal ctermfg:Blue).

Many thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect the `Conceal` highlighting is overriden by your colorscheme os something like that. You will see where it is defined with `:verbose highlight Conceal`, which should show an output similar to this:

```
:verbose hi Conceal
Conceal        xxx ctermfg=4 guifg=#268bd2
        Last set from ~/.vim/colors/my_colorscheme.vim line 1234
```

I suggest you read [this writeup by romainl](https://gist.github.com/romainl/379904f91fa40533175dfaec4c833f2f) to learn how to properly override highlighting outside of a colorscheme script.

---

By the way, from version 2.0 of Vimtex, you don't need to specify `g:tex_favor`, unless you explicitly want to set it to `context` or `plaintex`.

Comment: Thanks, this did the trick. Apparently indentLine was overriding my colour setting (and not my colorscheme weirdly), since I don't use it anyway I just removed it and everything works now.